# How would I send data from labels from a table view row action to a view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I'm trying to pass the data from a table view cell to another view controller through the cell's 'edit' table view row action.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (action, indexPath) in

        let editViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditViewController") as! EditViewController
        self.present(editViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        let cell = self.recipeList[indexPath.row] as? RecipeTableViewCell

        editViewController.nameTextField.text = cell?.recipeNameLabel.text
    }

    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 167.0/255.0, green: 204.0/255.0, blue: 181.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    return [edit]
}
```

This is my cell for row act function...

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RecipeCell", for: indexPath) as! RecipeTableViewCell

    let recipe = recipeList[indexPath.row]

    cell.recipeNameLabel!.text = recipe.name
    cell.ratingControl.rating = recipe.rating
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You should reuse your cells! Not store a cell for every row you have!

Comment: show your `cellRowAt`  method as well

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing each value in your target VC, try to pass `recipe` object only. Then get values from that object and fill in your controls.

1) create `recipe` object in your `EditViewController`

```
 var editRecipe : Recipe! // Your Model class
```

2) Assign values

```
let editViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditViewController") as! EditViewController
editViewController. editRecipe = recipeList[indexPath.row]
self.present(editViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

3) in `ViewDidload` of `EditViewController`

```
if editRecipe != nil {
    //Fill data in lbls
    //lbl_name.text = editRecipe.name
}
```